# Jump to end of progress bar when complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have working but ugly solution.

Idea is:

1. Run progress bar before ajax call
2. Jump to end of progress bar when complete (or fail)
3. Wait at 90% if ajax call is not finished yet (when finish than jump to end)

There are at least three problems in my solution:

1. I have to reset progress bar 'width' in 3 places.
2. I must have public variable (widthProgressBar)
3. I cannot reuse function 'startProgress' in case I want to have two progress bars at same page.

This is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/WQXXT/5403/

```js
var widthProgressBarPing = 0;
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getSuccessOutput() {
  widthProgressBar = 0;
  startProgress("pingTestBar");
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function(response) {
      widthProgressBar = 99;
    },
    error: function() {
      widthProgressBar = 99;
    },
  });
  return false;
}

function startProgress(barId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(barId);
  var id = setInterval(frame, 15);

  function frame() {
    if (widthProgressBar >= 90 && widthProgressBar < 99) {}
    if (widthProgressBar >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      widthProgressBar++;
      elem.style.width = widthProgressBar + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = widthProgressBar * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.testProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.testProgressBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput();"> test success </a> |
<div class="testProgress">
  <div id="pingTestBar" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the right approach, without changing unnecessary variables outside usage scope.

```js
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getSuccessOutput() {
  var bar = new Bar("pingTestBar");
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function(response) {
      bar.finish()
    },
    error: function() {
      bar.finish()
    },
  });
  return false;
}



function Bar(barId) {
  var self = this;
  self.w = 0;
  var elem = document.getElementById(barId);
  var id = setInterval(frame, 15);
  
  this.finish = function(){
    clearInterval(id);
    self.w = 100;
    changeElem()
  }
  
  function changeElem(){
  elem.style.width = self.w + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = self.w * 1 + '%';
  }
  
  function frame() {
    if (self.w >= 90 && self.w < 99) {}
    if (self.w >= 100) {
      
    } else {
      self.w++;
      changeElem()
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.testProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.testProgressBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput();"> test success </a> |
<div class="testProgress">
  <div id="pingTestBar" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code modified.

I eliminated the global var `widthProgressBarPing` by using the width of the `barId` element that's always there (`var widthProgressBar = elem.style.width.slice(0, -4);`).

```js
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getSuccessOutput(barId) {
  widthProgressBar = 0;
  startProgress(barId);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function(response) {
      widthProgressBar = 99;
    },
    error: function() {
      widthProgressBar = 99;
    },
  });
  return false;
}

function startProgress(barId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(barId);
  var widthProgressBar = elem.style.width.slice(0, -4);
  var id = setInterval(frame, 15);

  function frame() {
    if (widthProgressBar >= 90 && widthProgressBar < 99) {}
    if (widthProgressBar >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      widthProgressBar++;
      elem.style.width = widthProgressBar + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = widthProgressBar * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.testProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.testProgressBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput('pingTestBar');"> test success </a> ||
<div class="testProgress">
  <div id="pingTestBar" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>
```

By passing an argument to `startProgress(barId)` you can use the same function for different bars.

```js
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getSuccessOutput(barId) {
  widthProgressBar = 0;
  startProgress(barId);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function(response) {
      widthProgressBar = 99;
    },
    error: function() {
      widthProgressBar = 99;
    },
  });
  return false;
}

function startProgress(barId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(barId);
  var widthProgressBar = elem.style.width.slice(0, -4);
  var id = setInterval(frame, 15);

  function frame() {
    if (widthProgressBar >= 90 && widthProgressBar < 99) {}
    if (widthProgressBar >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      widthProgressBar++;
      elem.style.width = widthProgressBar + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = widthProgressBar * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.testProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.testProgressBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput('pingTestBar');"> test success </a> ||
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput('pingTestBar2');"> test success2 </a>
<div class="testProgress">
  <div id="pingTestBar" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>

<div class="testProgress">
  <div id="pingTestBar2" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **[cut]** There are at least three problems in my solution:
>
> 1. I have to reset progress bar 'width' in 3 places
> 2. I must have public
>      variable (widthProgressBar)
> 3. I cannot reuse function 'startProgress' in
>      case I want to have two progress bars at same page.

1. Simply initialize/reset once when `getSuccessOutput()` starts
2. Use the width attribute stored on each bar
3. Pass the "bar" as arguments, so you can use many bars as you need.

Anyway, you could use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in order to show the progress, so you avoid to keep interval id and the code is more readable.

Please, take a look to following snippet:

```js
function getSuccessOutput() {
  //Reset all progress bars
  $(".testProgressBar").width(0);
  $(".testProgressBar").text("");
  
  //Start requests
  doRequest($("#pingTestBar"), 1200);
  doRequest($("#pingTestBar2"), 1500);
  doRequest($("#pingTestBar3"), 800);
}

function startProgress(bar) {
  bar.animate(
    {
      width:'100%'
    },
    {
      step: function() {
              setText(bar);
            },
      duration: 2000
    }
 );
}

function complete(bar) {
  console.log("Complete " + bar.attr('id'));
  bar.finish().animate(
    {
      width:'100%'
    },
    {
      step: function(){
              setText(bar);
            }
    }
 );
}

function setText(bar){
  var text = bar.width() / bar.parent().width() * 100;
  bar.text(text.toFixed(0));
}

function mockAjax(options) {
  var that = {
    done: function done(callback) {
      if (options.success)
        setTimeout(callback, options.timeout, options.response);
      return that;
    },
    error: function error(callback) {
      if (!options.success)
        setTimeout(callback, options.timeout, options.response);
      return that;
    }
  };
  return that;
}

function doRequest(bar, duration){
  var mock = {
    ajax: function() {
      return mockAjax({
        success: true,
        response: {},
        timeout: duration
      });
    }
  };
  
  startProgress(bar);
  
  mock.ajax()
    .done(
          function (response) { 
            complete(bar);
          }
    )
    .error(
          function (response) { 
            complete(bar);
          }
    );
}
```

```css
.testProgress {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

.testProgressBar {
        width: 0%;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 30px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput();"> test success </a> |
<div class="testProgress">
     <div id="pingTestBar" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>
<div class="testProgress">
     <div id="pingTestBar2" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>
<div class="testProgress">
     <div id="pingTestBar3" class="testProgressBar"></div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.